# How do I ensure data is written to disk before closing fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream

The following looks sensible, but I've heard that the data could theoretically still be in a buffer rather than on the disk, even after the close() call.

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    ofstream fsi("test.txt");

    fsi << "Hello World";

    fsi.flush();

    fsi.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that's an operating system detail that's not exposed in the standard C++ library.  You could either not fret about it and trust the OS to get this right or give very specific details about what OS and compiler you use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot to this with standard tools and have to rely on OS facilities.
For POSIX `fsync` should be what you need. As there is no way to a get C file descriptor from a standard stream you would have to resort to C streams in your whole application or just open the file for flushing do disk. Alternatively there is `sync` but this flushes **all** buffers, which your users and other applications are going to hate.

Comment: Why would other apps hate it? You could always do that in a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

You could guarantee the data from the buffer is written to disk by flushing the stream. That could be done by calling its `flush()` member function, the `flush` manipulator, the `endl` manipulator.

However, there is no need to do so in your case since `close` guarantees that any pending output sequence is written to the physical file.

> § 27.9.1.4 / 6:
>
> basic_filebuf< charT, traits >* close();
>
> Effects: If is_open() == false, returns a null pointer. If a put area exists, calls overflow(traits::eof()) to ﬂush characters. (...)

Comment: The language can't guarantee the data is immediately written to the physical file. Most filesystems have a write-cache which intermediates the write operation. To bypass this cache, one needs to use non-buffered I/O, aka direct I/O (`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` on Windows, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system are you using?

You need to use Direct (non-buffered) I/O to guarantee the data is written directly to the physical device without hitting the filesystem write-cache. Be aware it still has to pass thru the disk cache before getting physically written.

On Windows, you can use the [FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99794) flag when opening the file.

Comment: `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` doesn't work reliably. E.g. with SATA devices "through" will only mean "through to" the cache of the HDD/SSD. You should use `FlushFileBuffers` instead.

Comment: @PaulGroke `FlushFileBuffers` [they say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx#3) is broken in Win 7.

Comment: @Eugene Ryabtsev: I'm aware of those comments. If I understand correctly that bug doesn't "require" FlushFileBuffers to be called though. And I can only hope that MS has fixed that bug. I would really be surprised if not, because I'd like to assume that something like this has top priority.

Answer (score 0):

> § 27.9.1.4
>   basic_filebuf* close();
>   Effects: If is_open() == false, returns a null pointer. **If a put area
>   exists, calls overflow(traits::eof()) to flush characters.** If the last
>   virtual member function called on *this (between underflow, overflow,
>   seekoff, and seekpos) was overflow then calls a_codecvt.unshift
>   (possibly several times) to determine a termination sequence, inserts
>   those characters and **calls overflow(traits::eof()) again.** Finally,
>   regardless of whether any of the preceding calls fails or throws an
>   exception, the function closes the file (as if by calling
>   std::fclose(file)).  If any of the calls made by the function,
>   including std::fclose, fails, close fails by returning a null pointer.
>   If one of these calls throws an exception, the exception is caught and
>   rethrown after closing the file.

It's guaranteed to flush the file.  However, note that the *OS* might keep it cached, and the *OS* might not flush it immmediately.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure the whole point of calling `close()` is to flush the buffer.  [This site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/close/) agrees.  Although depending on your file system and mount settings, just because you've 'written to the disk' doesn't mean that your file system drivers and disk hardware have actually taken the data and made magnet-y bits on the physical piece of metal.  It could probably be in a disk buffer still.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html This site does not (for Linux).  At the bottom, it explicitly says it can only flush the application-level buffers, not necessarily the kernel buffers.

Answer (score -2):

The `close()` member function closes the underlying OS file descriptor. At that point, the file should be on disk.

Comment: I don't want to take risks - I need to check for any possible error that might occur, and then warn the user of the application to attempt saving the file at a later time.

Comment: it's up to the OS to decide when it actually writes that data to the disk, isn't?

Comment: There are no 100% guarantees. The OS could physically flush the data, and the next time you go to read it, it has become corrupted by a gamma ray or something. The OS saying, "It's on disk," is as much guarantee as you're likely to get or need. If you are really paranoid, then do your own ECC.

Answer (score -3):

How abt [flushing](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/flush/) before closing?

Comment: That's exactly what `close()` does: it flushes before closing. Unless you are suggesting to flush before flushing before closing. That would be silly.

Comment: Yes, it's silly indeed. Didn't see the `close()`, assumed it was a simpler question. :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes no `close()` does not `flush()` before closing