# Testing write/read speed on NTFS, FAT, EXT4

Tags: c++, c, benchmarking, fat32, ext4

I have to write a program in C (or C++) in `Linux` that will tests write and read speed on different file systems. I have to be sure that all data are written to the disk (not in cache).

So my first question - what function should I use to open a new file? I used before `open` function with parameters `O_DIRECT` and `O_SYNC` and everything was fine except one thing - writing small files like 1KB was extremely slow, something like 0.01MB/s.

I tried to use `fopen` function instead `open`, and `fflush` function to be sure that all data writes direct to the disk, and I tested it first on `FAT32` file system. 1000 files with 1KB was written to disk (here SD card) in 5 sec. something like 0.18MB/s, and I think that is correct.

Now the problem occurs when testing `EXT4` and `NTFS` file systems. On `EXT4`. 1KB files was written something like 12MB/s (wrong), when testing 100KB transfer was 180MB/s (terribly wrong, my SD card has transfer rate only 20MB/s).

My actually code for write files looks like this:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

for ( int i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
{
    p = fopen(buffer2, "w+");

    fwrite(buff, size*1024, 1, p);
    if ( fflush(p) != 0 ) { cout << "fflush error"; return 0; } 

    fclose(p);
}

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts2);

time2 = diff2(ts,ts2);
```

works only good for `FAT32` file system. The second code (used before) looks like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
{
    int fd = open(buffer2, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777);
    if ( error(fd, "open") ) return false;

    if ( (write(fd, buff, size*1024)) < 0 ) { perror("write error"); return 0; }

    if ( (fsync(fd)) == -1 ) { perror("fsync"); return 0; }

    close(fd);
}
```

works for all file systems but small files writes extremely slow.
Maybe I should use different code for different file system? Any ideas?

`EDIT`:

I have found why writing small files is slow. It is because of `fsync` function, and on different file systems it takes different time. I am calling `fsync` every write, so here is the problem.

Is there any way to call it at the end, when all files are written? Or maybe every few seconds? Does I have to use different thread?

Comment: Look at the `fsync` function. It makes sure that the file behind a file descriptor is correctly synced to disk. Both O_DIRECT and O_SYNC will probably give you worse total performance.

Comment: Depending on why you need to do this you may be better off using an existing performance test. Take a look at [IOZone](http://www.iozone.org/). The source is available so if you ever want to look at how someone else has approached a particular test you have a well tested reference.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, please.

Comment: Or [Bonnie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/), which may be easier if you're custom building it for your platform.

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I ensure data is written to disk before closing fstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522479/how-do-i-ensure-data-is-written-to-disk-before-closing-fstream) but I don't think you can ensure that data is actually on disk rather than in a cache in the disk controller or even in the drive's onboard cache