# Can "eof" be set in ofstream?

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

I could not find pretty much any information on this. Whether and if so, under what circumstances, can eofbit be set (meaning ofstream_instance.eof() is true )?

I am more interested in an independent ofstream, one that is not associated with an ifstream within some fstream, so that the "shared" eofbit can't be set by the ifstream (if something like that is possible).

If I simply write to a file and there is no space on disk or operation system does not provide another space for the writing, then I'd expect just only either failbit  or badbit to be set, but reaching end of file while writing to it does not make sense to me. However no discussion on this I was able to find.

Comment: I still don't get why it should be necessary to set `eof` bit in `std::ofstream`. If you `close()` the `std::ofsteam` and it doesn't fail I would assume that output was successfully. Though, I somewhere read that this is true "above" OS level only. To grant this for the harddisk may take even more effort (beyond std C++) e.g. doing an `fsync()`. (My stomache was right - found:) [SO: How do I ensure data is written to disk before closing fstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522650/7478597)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.** `eof()` returns the `eofbit`, which has no real meaning for an output stream with no associated input stream.

> `eofbit` indicates that an input operation reached the end of an input sequence
>
> [**[ios.types]** / 3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/ios::iostate), Table 107

The actions that set `eofbit` are enumerated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate), and they all act on input streams only.

We could imagine some weird implementation-specific scenario in which EOF (as opposed to some other error condition) would be hit while writing to a file - maybe there is a fixed-size file buffer we are writing to through some OS functions - but as far as I know the standard library abstractions do not deal with that case, and I have never seen or heard of such an API in the first place.

Comment: I've been thinking that for instance on a FAT32 filesystem, when reaching the 4GB marker, there might be enforced EOF. But that seems unlikely, I am just thinking "out loud".

Comment: On that note, there is an `errno` of EFBIG for when this happens with POSIX `write`. I imagine that that would map to `failbit` or `badbit` though, because usually that is an error (as opposed to EOF, which is normal and expected behavior)